# WordPress: How to redirect all tag feed URLs to their respective tag URL?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, feed

I want to 301 redirect all tag feed URLs to their tag URL on my WordPress site.

I want to redirect `www.example.com/tag/???/feed` to `www.example.com/tag/???/`

"???" can be anything.

For example:

- `www.example.com/tag/aaa/feed` ==> `www.example.com/tag/aaa/`
- `www.example.com/tag/any-thing/feed` ==> `www.example.com/tag/any-thing/`

How can I do that? Please help me

I tried with Yoast SEO REGEX redirects but I can't find right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression pattern to search for would be something like this:

```
^\/tag\/(.+?)\/feed\/?$
```

And the URL to redirect to would be similar to this:

```
/tag/$1/
```

If that doesn’t work, then [the `do_feed_{$feed}` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_feed_feed/) may be another option.